# Set Max zoom level for mapview using MapMyIndia android sdk

Tags: android, mapmyindia-api

I am using mapmyindia mapview to add some markermodels. In some cases the markers are very close to each other and it becomes tough for the user to click on them. If I set the maxzoomlevel for mapview greater than 18 then the map distorts on zooming and if the maxzoomlevel is 18 then it doesn't allow the user to zoom further.Kindly suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: Hi @Ishita can you share some code snippet.

Comment: mMapView.maxZoomLevel = 18. If I set it greater than 18 then the map distorts on zooming after a certain point.

Comment: Max Zoom 18 is what we are supporting in our raster SDK, request you to try new vector sdk.